# How do I multiply ranges from another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

In "Sheet 1" there are two columns: "Weight" and "Value". Like:

5 100

2 200

In "Sheet 2" I want to have a cell with a value of weighted average from "Sheet 1". It should be calculated like this (5*100+2*200)/(5+2). Is it possible to calculate this with formula in a single cell?

I only succeed doing this with intermediary column of multiplication values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!B:B)/SUM(Sheet1!A:A)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. 
Can you give me a hint if this formula could be augmented to exclude non number values from ranges A:A and B:B?